# Why is the inserted image showing as a bunch of flat images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have made a character fighting simulation website, but when you enter in the image for a character, it just makes the image appear as flat and a wallpaper instead of the original resolution. The purpose of this was to test my knowledge of html after a few months of not using it, aswell as to test some features to see if I can incorporate it into another project later on.
This is my script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

var characterList = [];
var characterListDiv = document.createElement('div');
characterListDiv.id = 'characterListDiv';
document.body.appendChild(characterListDiv);

var characterNameInput = document.createElement('input');
characterNameInput.id = 'characterNameInput';
characterNameInput.placeholder = 'Character Name';
document.body.appendChild(characterNameInput);

var characterImageInput = document.createElement('input');
characterImageInput.id = 'characterImageInput';
characterImageInput.placeholder = 'Character Image URL';
document.body.appendChild(characterImageInput);

var addCharacterButton = document.createElement('button');
addCharacterButton.id = 'addCharacterButton';
addCharacterButton.innerHTML = 'Add Character';
addCharacterButton.onclick = function() {
  var characterName = document.getElementById('characterNameInput').value;
  var characterImage = document.getElementById('characterImageInput').value;
  var character = {
    name: characterName,
    image: characterImage
  };
  characterList.push(character);
  var characterDiv = document.createElement('div');
  characterDiv.innerHTML = character.name;
  characterDiv.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + character.image + ')';
  characterListDiv.appendChild(characterDiv);
};
document.body.appendChild(addCharacterButton);

var fightButton = document.createElement('button');
fightButton.id = 'fightButton';
fightButton.innerHTML = 'Fight';
fightButton.onclick = function() {
  var characterListCopy = characterList.slice();
  var fightResults = [];
  while (characterListCopy.length > 1) {
    var character1 = characterListCopy.pop();
    var character2 = characterListCopy.pop();
    var winner = Math.random() > 0.5 ? character1 : character2;
    var loser = winner === character1 ? character2 : character1;
    fightResults.push({
      winner: winner,
      loser: loser
    });
    characterListCopy.push(winner);
  }
  var fightResultsDiv = document.createElement('div');
  fightResultsDiv.id = 'fightResultsDiv';
  document.body.appendChild(fightResultsDiv);
  fightResults.forEach(function(fightResult) {
    var fightResultDiv = document.createElement('div');
    fightResultDiv.innerHTML = fightResult.winner.name + ' beat ' + fightResult.loser.name;
    fightResultsDiv.appendChild(fightResultDiv);
  });
};
document.body.appendChild(fightButton);
});
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

I have tried messing with the image section but nothing changes. Google doesn't help me.

Comment: Consider making a stackblitz/codepen example with your issue and link to that.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the whole image is not shown, then the cause is that a background image just uses the size of the div and not the size of the image.

You could solve that by giving the div a fixed height. You can also adjust the background size so that it always fills the whole div (cover) or shows the whole image (contain).

```
  characterDiv.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + character.image + ')';
  characterDiv.style.height = "300px";
  characterDiv.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
```